# Google maps autocomplete place_changed not firing

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am having a problem with the place_changed event not firing when I click on an item in the drop down. If I right-click an item then it fires. If I left-click then it will sometimes fire, but only about 10% of the time.

I have looked to see if there are any listeners that might be interfering, but I am not seeing any. If I trace into the Google maps code I can see that a click event seems to be firing, but it doesn't detect a change in the location field so the place_changed is not fired. So something seems to be preventing the location value from being set.

Here is the code where the autocomplete is set and the listener is set.

```
function initAnyGoogleAutocomplete(searchBoxElementId, placeChangedCallbackFunction) {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(document.getElementById(searchBoxElementId), 'place_changed');
    var searchBoxReferenceVar = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(searchBoxElementId),
    {
        bounds: map.getBounds(),
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBoxReferenceVar, 'place_changed', placeChangedCallbackFunction);

    return searchBoxReferenceVar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered the cause of the issue. The body was set to draggable and the drag event was bound to a function that returned false. That event was interfering with the location within the autocomplete from being set.